# Anyone help me with this PDE using Fourier Transform?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have this:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} + p\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}+\lambda p\frac{\partial^{2} c}{\partial z\partial t}-\frac{\partial^{2} c}{\partial z^2}=0\quad(1)$$
$$c(z,0)=\delta(z)$$

I attempted the solution using Fourier Transform and I got:
$$\mathcal F\{(1)\}\to \frac{dC}{dt}+p(i\omega)C+\lambda p(i\omega )\frac{dC}{dt}+\omega^2 C=0\quad(2)$$
$$\mathcal F\{c(z,0)\}=1$$
Note that $C(\omega,t)=\mathcal F\{c(z,t)\}$

Rearrange (2) I got:
$$C=\exp\left(-\frac{pi\omega+\omega^2}{\lambda pi\omega+1}t\right)$$

Then I don't know how to inverse Fourier Transform to the solution in time domain. I have heard of residue theorem but don't know how to use it. Would anyone verify my work and/or give insight into this? I have been stuck for two days now :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can put your integral into the form $$c = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\left(
\frac{-p \omega^2 z \lambda + i \omega z - t \omega^2 - i p t \omega}{i p \omega \lambda + 1}
\right)
\, d\omega$$ for which calculating the residue is really hard, as well as $$c= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\left(\frac{ B \omega^2}{D \omega^2 + 1}\right)
\cos\left(\frac{A\omega^3 + C\omega}{D \omega^2 + 1}\right)
\, d\omega$$ for $A=p^2z\lambda^2 + pt\lambda$, $B=-p^2t\lambda - t$, $C=z-pt$, but I think that inverting the Fourier transform won't be easy.

Comment: Btw, I get the same result for $C$ as you.

Comment: Thank you for your response DanielV. I have asked my TA as well and he told me the integral should be standard enough to work out. Also, thank you for the verification!

Comment: Haha, I await the solution from your TA then.  Anyway, I asked this question to me help solve your problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745076/complex-residue-involving-exponent-of-quotient-of-polynomials , check out the accepted answer to help you if you try to apply the cauchy residue theorem.  Is this homework or part of research?

Comment: It is not a part of my research but only a part of a set of problems. Thank you so much for putting it on another thread and help me find the answer. Honestly I don't usually come across what is mentioned in the answer to your question in another thread. Stuffs like Laurent series and Bessel function, I don't have much knowledge of those. I don't think it should be complicated like that. I haven't even studied the residue theorem for Fourier Transform to the fullest. For sure I'll follow you up with an answer soon.

Comment: Thank you I look forward to it, this website even encourages answering your own question if you get a chance.  Please leave a comment here if you do post an answer so I know to look.